# What percentage of Frenchmen still think [hydroxy]chloroquine is an effective remedy against Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, public-opinion, france

[News](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/04/france-s-president-fueling-hype-over-unproven-coronavirus-treatment) from almost two months ago:

> A survey released by French polling institute IFOP on 6 April revealed that 59% of the French population believes chloroquine is effective against the new coronavirus. Confidence in the drugs is higher on the far right and far left, and reached 80% among sympathizers of the “yellow vest” movement that staged massive protests against Macron’s economic policy in 2018 and 2019. Support is also very high, at 74%, in the Marseille region.

Didier Raoult, a prominent French microbiologist who has promoted the drug in some [controversial studies](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2020/03/29/more-on-cloroquine-azithromycin-and-on-dr-raoult) works in Marseille. Also Raoult's studies have been [hyped up on Fox News shows](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/12/magazine/didier-raoult-hydroxychloroquine.html), thus having a trans-Atlantic impact... and further beyond, becoming a sort of article of faith of some right-wing movements, in the Americas [at least](https://www.france24.com/en/20200520-bolsonaro-bets-big-on-right-wing-drug-against-virus):

> Brazilian President Jair Bolsonaro neatly sums up how thoroughly politics has hijacked the debate over using malaria drugs against the new coronavirus: "Right-wingers take chloroquine."

So, I'm naturally curious if approximately two months later the French public opinion still expresses the same high degree of confidence in chloroquine or hydroxychloroquine, or if there have been significant changes in that regard. I.e. have there been any new polls in France on the population's belief in chloroquine/hydroxychloroquine as a cure for Covid-19, particularly correlating it with the political orientation of the respondents?

Comment: The whole thing is still regularly discussed in the press (including today on lemonde.fr) but I don't recall any new polls and couldn't find any on news.google.fr.

Comment: Considering that Lancet yesterday retracted the study about HCQ being ineffective, popularity of the cure exploded https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/jun/04/covid-19-lancet-retracts-paper-that-halted-hydroxychloroquine-trials